# What should I pay attention to when using WebClient to replace RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: newSocketStream(..) failed: Too many open files

I am searching for a long time on the net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas on how to achieve this.

spring-boot: 2.3.1.RELEASE

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
  public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder) throws SSLException {
    final SslContext sslContext =
        SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();
    HttpClient httpClient =
        HttpClient.create().secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext));

    return builder.clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();
  }

  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
  }
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class WebClientTestController {

  private final WebClient webClient;

  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public WebClientTestController(WebClient webClient, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.webClient = webClient;
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }

  @GetMapping("/webclient")
  public Mono<Object> main() {

    new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()
        .execute(
            () -> {
              for (int i = 0; i <= 65536; ++i) {
                System.out.println(
                    webClient
                            .get()
                            .uri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello")
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(String.class)
                            .block()
                        + i);
              }
            });

    return Mono.empty();
  }

  @GetMapping("/restTemplate")
  public Mono<Object> main2() {

    new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()
        .execute(
            () -> {
              for (int i = 0; i <= 65536; ++i) {
                System.out.println(
                    restTemplate.getForEntity("http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello", String.class).getBody()
                        + i);
              }
            });

    return Mono.empty();
  }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class GreetingHandler {
  public Mono<ServerResponse> hello(ServerRequest request) {
    return ServerResponse.ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromValue("Hello, Spring!"));
  }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class GreetingRouter {
  @Bean
  public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(GreetingHandler greetingHandler) {

    return RouterFunctions.route(
        RequestPredicates.GET("/hello").and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)),
        greetingHandler::hello);
  }
}
```

request in windows:

```sh
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/restTemplate
```

```
...
Hello, Spring!65535
Hello, Spring!65536
```

```sh
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/webclient
```

```
...
Hello, Spring!65535
Hello, Spring!65536
```

request in Linux:

```sh
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/restTemplate
```

```
...
Hello, Spring!65535
Hello, Spring!65536
```

```sh
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/webclient
```

```
Hello, Spring!10196
Hello, Spring!10197
Exception in thread "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" io.netty.channel.ChannelException: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: newSocketStream(..) failed: Too many open files
        at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.newSocketStream0(Socket.java:421)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket.newSocketStream(LinuxSocket.java:319)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket.newSocketStream(LinuxSocket.java:323)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel.<init>(EpollSocketChannel.java:45)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopEpoll.getChannel(DefaultLoopEpoll.java:45)
        at reactor.netty.resources.LoopResources.onChannel(LoopResources.java:187)
        at reactor.netty.resources.LoopResources.onChannel(LoopResources.java:169)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources.onChannel(TcpResources.java:215)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpTcpClient.connect(HttpClientConnect.java:141)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientOperator.connect(TcpClientOperator.java:43)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientOperator.connect(TcpClientOperator.java:43)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientOperator.connect(TcpClientOperator.java:43)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientOperator.connect(TcpClientOperator.java:43)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient.connect(TcpClient.java:202)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientFinalizer.connect(HttpClientFinalizer.java:77)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientFinalizer.responseConnection(HttpClientFinalizer.java:94)
        at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector.connect(ReactorClientHttpConnector.java:111)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$exchange$0(DefaultWebClient.java:338)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4219)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1678)
        at com.example.demo.controller.WebClientTestController.lambda$main$0(WebClientTestController.java:38)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
                at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1679)
                ... 2 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: newSocketStream(..) failed: Too many open files
```

≈ ulimit -n

Where is wrong? I hope to learn more details.

Comment: Where it is wrong... Ehrm 1. why the executor? 2. you are blocking, why?

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you for your answer sincerely, 
This is just an example,I am learning and I don't know why it is wrong to use this way.

Comment: When is the thread closed?

Comment: You aren't creating that many threads, but the threads are never closed. Unless they get collected. What do you want to achieve? I fyou want to learn then just follow the guide.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

NOTE: As of 5.0 this class is in maintenance mode, with only minor requests for changes and bugs to be accepted going forward. Please, consider using the org.springframework.web.reactive.client.WebClient which has a more modern API and supports sync, async, and streaming scenarios.


If I use webclient instead of resttemplate, this will cause problems. This code uses resttemplate to run well in Linux.


So I want to know more webclient details.

Comment: Still unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @M.Deinum Replace resttemplate with webclient，What details do I need to pay attention to, such as this error, it is normal to use resttemplate

Comment: Your question is about learning `WebClient` you link to a guide which explains how it works. The code you post has no relation to that guide. And now it is to replace `RestTemplate`. If you want to replace it then replace it, but don't write code like you did here and try to learn it. The guide explains how it works and not sure how your code relates to that.

Comment: I should learn how to describe the problem, my fault